# Does AD FS 2.0 require claim-aware agent?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, adfs2.0

I noticed that for AD FS 1.0 server there is an adfs claim-aware agent for it's web server.
I wonder if AD FS 2.0 server works the same way and require a claim-aware agent 2.0 for web services? If so, how can I install this claim-aware agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - it doesn't. It has no concept of agents. ADFS supports passive (browser) and active (web services) directly.